# How to create a FabricJS image from PNG data returned by a web service?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a page with a FabricJS canvas. When the user presses a certain button, a request is sent to a web service. The response contains the data of a PNG image, which I want to insert into the canvas.

In the code snippet below, the image data is contained in $xhr.responseText.

```
function downloadButtonPressed() {
    var username = $("input#username").val();
    var password = $("input#password").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://myserver/myapp/map",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password),
          },
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            alert("success");
        }
    }).fail(function ($xhr) {
        console.log("response: " + $xhr);
        // Here, $xhr.responseText contains the data of the PNG image
    });
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

I want to add the PNG image from `$xhr.responseText` to a FabricJS canvas.

How can I do it?

There is a method `fabric.Image.fromURL`, but I need something, which converts a string (or a byte stream) to a FabricJS image.

Comment: If you really need credentials, I think you'll have to come back to built-in `XMLHttpRequest`, instead of `$.ajax`and set the `xhr.responseType` to `'blob'`, then read the response with a `FileReader.readAsDataURL` that you will be able to pass through the `fabric.Image.fromURL` method. But if you don't care about tainting the canvas, just passing the ajax's url to `fabric.Image.fromURL` should also work.

Comment: from what i understood the url contain an image just in case of response 500. so he should first call the url, check response and then pass the url again to loadFromURL, that would be loading twice.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi yes in a way it would load twice, but the second loading would be from a clean dataURI, there will be only one request to the server and it won't taint the canvas since no cross-origin is involved anymore. So there will be two parsing and a single fetching.

Comment: Good reference : https://itnext.io/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-fabric-js-95d44b727373

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your response text is a binary string containing the image data, you can build a dataurl and from datayurl load a standard image.

```
function downloadButtonPressed() {
    var username = $("input#username").val();
    var password = $("input#password").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://myserver/myapp/map",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password),
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            alert("success");
        }
    }).fail(function ($xhr) {
        var myDataURL = "data:image/png;base64," + btoa($xhr.responseText);
        var img = document.createElement("IMG");
        img.onload = function(){
            var fImg = new fabric.Image(img, {options});
        }
        img.src = myDataURL
    });
}
```

If your response is a utf8 string, thus generating an error for illegal character, as stated by MDN, try this alternative solution to convert it in base 64:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa

```
function utf8_to_b64(str) {
    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
}

btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent($xhr.responseText)));
```

Comment: In `var myDataURL = "data:image/png;base64," + btoa($xhr);`, shouldn't it be `$xhr.responseText` instead of `$xhr`?

Comment: You will certainly get a `InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character` or `Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.` doing so with `btoa()`

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, I'm getting that error. How can I fix it? I have control over both client and server side.

Comment: Maybe some other base64 encoding libraries are able to encode more charsets. Or, have you tried what I said in the comment on your question?

Comment: you can try the alternative i just added to the response. there is also link from MDN with some usefull information

Comment: That's strange MDN adviced to use `unescape`/`escape` since those are deprecated. But from my tests it still doesn't work, even if it does avoid the character error

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi Thanks. Now the `InvalidCharacterError` is gone. A different error occurs, though: `Uncaught TypeError: function createElement() { [native code] } is not a constructor`. It must be `var img = document.createElement("IMG");`, without `new`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    axios
        .get(imgSrcURl, {
                responseType: 'arraybuffer'
            })
        .then(response => {
            var data_url = Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64');
            data_url = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + data_url;
            fabric.Image.fromURL(
                data_url,
                img => {
                    resolve(img);
                });
        });
});
```

Comment: Please add some description of what this code does.